# how to test private / protected class variable when set to default type

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, typeerror, php-7.2

This is a simplified example, understand the problem.

The code works I have a problem when I want to test phpUnit

> IBase.php

```
namespace interfaces;
interface IBase {}
```

> FileNavigate.php

```
class FileNavigate {

 private IBase $f3; // <= line: 5 #RED

 public function __construct(IBase $f3, $file = '') { // <= #GREEN use IBase
  $this->f3 = $f3;
  }
}
```

> FileNavigateTest.php

```
declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FileNavigateTest extends TestCase {

 public function testInterface() {
   $mock = $this->createMock(\interfaces\IBase::class);
   $f3_get_FileNavigate = new FileNavigate($mock); // <= line: 10

   $this->assertTrue(true);
 }

}
```

> cmd:

```
PHPUnit 8.5.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.                                                         
                                                                                                               
..E...                                                              1 / 1 (100%)                               
                                                                                                               
Time: 8 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB                                                                                   
                                                                                                               
There was 1 error:                                                                                             
                                                                                                               
1) FileNavigateTest::testInterface                                                                             
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'IBase' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)    
                                                                                                               
/html/app/v2/FileNavigate.php:5                                                            
/html/tests/FileNavigateTest.php:10                                                                
                                                                                                               
ERRORS!                                                                                                        
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.                                                                            
Script ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests handling the test event returned with error code 2                           
Script @test was called via t
```

I know the error is in the file "FileNavigate.php" on line 5

Only my IDE works better when I use this notation.

> Anyone know how to test it?

The class is to test whether the object it receives has this interface,
mock replaces a class that already has this interface.

Comment: This is a simplified example, understand the problem.
the class is to test if the object has this interface, the class is not mock here

Comment: Tryed your code - works fine. I think problem in namespaces - try to follow PSR standards.

Comment: @Maksim The code works fine and it's version 2, I'm rewriting it for php 7 and wanted to use variable typing and it works fine. I have a problem when I want to test phpUnit

Answer (score 0):

In the **FileNavigate.php** file use phpdoc:
An importent comment takes the form of:

```
/** @var IBase */
private $f3;
```

or

```
/** @param IBase $f3 */
private $f3;
```

not

```
/* <= bad form
* @var IBase
*/
private $f3;
```

maybe that's why your IDE can't see types